# How to declare int variable to be visible to all my methods?

Tags: java, android

I have a game and start int value points = 100; and with game progress that value decreases after each click on a button, until the game ends. I subtrack points in onClick method in using switch. After game ends, I reload game method once more for second round and here is my problem. If I make that int variable an instance variable, it will keep it's value after first round ended, and I need to start again from 100. If I declare it as local variable my method that calls another activity using intent and sending final points value will not see this variable. How to solve this?

So, I declare some variables:

```
int numberPointsGame = 100;
static int numberPointsTotal;
```

Now, on my onClick method I set some text and subtrack those points:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.bA1:
            numberPointsGame = numberPointsGame - 5;
            a1.setText(mA1);
            break;
        case R.id.bA2:
            numberPointsGame = numberPointsGame - 5;
            a2.setText(mA2);
            break;
```

And now, if a user enter correct answer, I place that points in another instance variable and then send it to another popup activity and then reload first activity and do it once more time.

```
if (ukucanRezultatStrK.equals(konacanNormalized)){
                                                        konacnoResenje.setText(mKonacno);


                                                        Intent i = new Intent(Asocijacije.this, Popup_asocijacije.class);
                                                        i.putExtra("brojPoenaPrimljeno", numberPointsGame);
                                                        startActivity(i);

                                                        mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,3700);

                                                        numberPointsTotal = numberPointsTotal + numberPointsGame;

                                                        setResults();


                                                 }else{
                                                    Toast.makeText(Asocijacije.this, "Wrong answer!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
```

And after second reload, when the game finish, I go to main menu and set final result (total of two game results) to a button. I ALWAYS GET 0. That's the main problem.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Izbor.class);
                i.putExtra("numberPointsGame", numberPointsTotal);
                startActivity(i);
```

and my main menu class:

```
int numberPointsGame;
    int score = 0;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

        setContentView(R.layout.izbor);

        addListenerOnButton();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras !=null) {
           score = extras.getInt("ukupnoAsocijacije", 0);
        }
    }

private void addListenerOnButton() {

poeniAso.setText("" + score);

}
```

Comment: please show relevant code.

Comment: why don't you affect 100 to your variable when the game reload?

Comment: What's the problem setting it back to 100?

Comment: Declare a static class with a static attribute. Whole should be public, then you just have to import package where you class is, then your attribute gonna be visible.

Comment: @Simon I do that, but let me place some code in my first post, to show you where is my problem. I explain in there.

Answer (score 1):

> I reload game method once more...

You could have some initialization code which could serve for this purpose... prepare all the necessary fields prior to the game starting:

```
public class Game
{
    private int myCounter;

    public void initialize()
    {
         this.myCounter = 100;
         //initialize canvas, connections, etc.
    }
}
```

Or else, simply have a `reset()` method in your code which is called prior to the game starting again.

Answer (score 1):

while moving from one activity to another, just pass the int along with the intent like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.putInt("MyImportantInt", someNumber);
```

and if its just a problem of visibility, try getter and setter ;) 
or in ur case a methode that just substracts 1 from the int everytime its called

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to avoid the creation of instance each time to access the points  use `Static`

```
 class PointsUtil{
    public static int  points =10   
    }
```

in any where in programm

```
PointsUtil.points= points+new points
```

When the method reload calls again

```
 PointsUtil.points= 10;
```

Comment: This did not work. I get error and need to remove static modifier, and then it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Try use java.lang.Integer instead of primitive int.